# How to install custom modules in Kohana 3 framework

Tags: php, kohana, captcha

I'm learning framework KohanaPhp 3 and I have a problem with adding a module called kolanos-Kohana-captcha.

What I've done so far is:

- I copied the directory kolanos-kohana-captcha into modules directory
- Copied kolanos-kohana-captcha/config/captcha.php to file application/config/captcha.php
- Edited the file and added Bootstrap.php

> Kohana::modules(array (... 'captcha'
>   => MODPATH."kolanos-kohana-captcha ', ));

But it does not work: (Whenever I want to use class Captcha kohana shows the error "class not found."

I'm doing something wrong?
Is this a problem with the module? There are some other modules to handle the captcha in Kohana 3+?

Comment: Are you using other modules? If so, do those modules work? Can you post a snippet of code where you are using the Captcha class?

Comment: Can you step back through the trace and see where it is looking for the module's class files?

Answer (score 4):

1. Original project name is *kohana-captcha*, not kolanos-kohana-captcha. May be you set incorrect directory name in bootstrap.php? Also, hosting servers are usually case sensitive, dont forget about it.
2. Use Kohana::modules(). It returns all modules loaded, so you will see, is it just Captcha problems or something else (you use wrong MODPATH value for example).
3. You can check Kohana class autoloading with Kohana::auto_load(), which will return TRUE/FALSE.